# Loss function for autoencoder on categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, loss-functions, autoencoders

I have some categorical variables that can take values {a,b,c}.
I have a dataset of sequences of such variables

E.g.

```
x=[ (a,b,b), (b,c,a)...]
```

I would like to apply some basic autoencoder to this dataset.
I could derive some meaningful latent space representation by mapping each categorical value to an arbitrary input a->0, b->1 etc.... and by using a simple encoder decoder model with mse loss between source and reconstructed (arbitrarly mapped) sequence.

What would be a more sound loss function in this case?

Comment: Is there an  inherit ordering between `c`, `b` and `a`? For example, is something like `a,a,b` closer to `a,a,a` than `a,a,c`? Otherwise, there is a number of [string  metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) that can be relevant.

Comment: I think string metrics would work. Can i use any of these as a loss function?

Comment: However there is also some weak ordering between the categorical values. That would be any alternatives to regression losses in that case?